# How to use the same emacs daemon for user and root accounts?

Tags: emacs

I often work in both user and root accounts but I don't like that I have two emacs daemons running for each user.

Is it possible to set the same, only one emacs daemon for user's and root's clients?

Comment: @drewbenn that interesting I never heard about `tramp` before but what I need is to point all the clients to the same server (daemon) so that will be tricky to use it for my propose if even it possible...

Comment: @drewbenn yes I was thinking about it after checking the first link. It's possible but mostly weird as solution because it will create big mess. If I want to commit by user I need to know that I use user's client and if I need to commit as root I need to commit as root... Right now I'm thinking about merging user account into root account because I really so often work as root so I don't know why I even need that user account.

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong.